# Mobo won't recognize 800 MHZ RAM?

Tags: memory, windows-installer, ddr2

My mobo, a decade-old [MSI P965 Neo](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/P965_Neo.html#hero-overview), will accept at most 4 slots of 2GB DDR2 DIMMs at 800 MHZ. I recently purchased 2 x 2 GB DIMMs at 800 MHZ to replace the 400 MHZ DIMMs that were onboard. Unfortunately, both `memtest` at startup as well as `CPU-Z` report 400 MHZ (399, to be exact). I'm wondering whether this is a problem that has to do with the memory itself, in which case I'll have to request replacements, or whether it would be something that could perhaps be solved with a BIOS upgrade of sorts.

Comment: In your BIOS, are the DIMM's set to some default profile that is set at 400MHZ?

Comment: @ben You were correct in your assumption; it was indeed set to a default profile which was at 400 MHz, and which I changed to 800. However, `memtest` still gives me 399 MHz: https://www.dropbox.com/sc/5co2ll21i98ra04/AABUHojoqvYy5j1AazN69Dnva

Comment: The first step is to verify your running the current firmware.

Comment: Just to make sure, would this mean that I need to install the latest BIOS? I can download that from their website.

Comment: @Jason - If you are not running the current firmware you should be.

Comment: I am currently on this. Updating the BIOS in my dual boot setup requires logging into MS-DOS, which is hard given said setup. Will update when successful.

Comment: Ok, so after three days of attempting to flash the BIOS through a billion different means, including re-installation of different Windows flavors about 5 or 6 times, I achieved to flash it to the most recent version. I plugged in a pair of 800 MHZ DIMMs, adjusted the BIOS as @Ben suggested, however CPU-Z still gives me a 400 MHZ reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check the Manufactures website to see if the modules have been tested as OK.

PC5300 DDR II RAM (DDR-667) 
NANYA NT2GT64U8HB0JY-3C 2GB 
appears to be listed at the only 2GB module that is supported, that's not to say that newer modules will not work that have just not been tested.

Looking at the list of modules http://www.msi.com/file/test_report/TR10_265.pdf
There are not listed 800mhz Modules that are 2GB in size.

Though the motherboard supports 8GB of memory it probably won't work unless its the 667 Memory.

In fact the website for this board states the following

Main Memory

• Supports four unbuffered DIMM of 1.8 Volt DDRII DRAM
• Supports up to 8GB memory size (DDRII 533/667).
• Supports up to 4GB memory size (DDRII 800).
• Supports dual channel DDRII memory architecture.
• Supports DDRII 533/667/800 memory interface.

http://www.msi.com/product/mb/P965_Neo.html#hero-specification

Comment: Right, those all appear to be fair points, unfortunately for me. I'm actually wondering the following too, though: I'm noticing from my BIOS settings that my FSB frequency is nothing close to 800MHz, and, unfortunately, there's no way it can approach it, since: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j91q8fz60sg9erm/2015-08-25%2010.17.52.jpg?dl=0

Is there any benefit to be had by increasing the FSB frequency up to the maximum of 500 to make the FSB / DRAM Freq ratio approach 1:1 as much as possible and, most importantly, is it safe?

Comment: For everyday use there's going to be little difference between the frequencies. Just run it until it's stable

Comment: Ok I just remembered that the reading your looking at is probably 400 would be 800, is double because of the fsb

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. So you're saying that I should clock the FSB at 400 without any further thought? Or perhaps I misread?

Comment: Actually, I tried increasing the FSB to 400 MHZ but that did not work either, I had to clear the CMOS in order to get the system operational again. I only have one final question to ask at this point: I found the 667 MHz Nanya DIMMs [online](http://ebay.to/1NXRxoi), yet only in 2 x 4GB. It's not clear to me, given the mobo's website and the bullet-points that you pointed out, whether the mobo is capable of carrying 4GB DIMMs in its slots, for a total of 2 x 4 = 8GBs. I'm not sure whether the 1.8 voltage would limit me to 2GBs; not aware of the connection between voltage and RAM capacity.

Comment: 400 would equal the 800 which the board won't support, just running the memory you have now at 667, 333. No need to buy more, just under clock what you have :)